# All order is not Migrated from Maento 1 to Magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, magento2.4, data-migration

I have Migrated data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 and my all data ( product , categories and customer ) are migrated correctly but the issue is the order which are migrated are from past 7 days.

Means if i run data migration on ( 13th Sep. ) so the order data which is migrated only upto ( 7th Sep. ) I have checked the Magento 1 db it has data in database table but the migration is not running completely.

Can anyone give an idea about why the data is not there and how to update that data also.

Thanks and any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using the trial version of Store Manager for Magento, filter orders by last 7 days and migrate them via export/import